# URL redirect for a domain & URL (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: redirect, rewrite, iis-8

I am shutting down an old intranet application, and in order to please my users, I would like to have a friendly page that tells them where they need to look instead.

Another team however have published a document that contains a link to the old application and won't change it.

So I'm stuck with a problem - how do I redirect the published link to a new location, and redirect all other traffic to the application to a friendly place.

For a single page for example:

`example.com/page/foo.aspx` redirects to `example.org`

For the entire domain for example:

`example.com` redirects to `example.org/information.html`

`example.com/anotherpage.aspx` also redirects to `example.org/information.html`

I've got this working for a single URL, however in IIS 8 I'm not sure what I should be putting to to a blanket redirect on the whole domain.

I assume I'd need to rank the rules too, so that the page is affected first, and then the blanket redirect.